# C# Server Client seems to only work one way

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

I'm trying to send data between a client and a server in C#. I'm fairly new to this. I'm running these on the same machine, hence localhost.

The server can receive data from the client but the client never seems to get the reply of yes even though it is sent.

**Client:**
The client sends data ("apple") to the server and should receive a reply.

```
       TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 1334); //Currently localhost
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

        string sendData = "apple";
        sw.WriteLine(sendData);
        sw.Flush();

        string data = sr.ReadLine();

        if (data != null)
        {
         MessageBox.Show("It worked!");
         }
         else
         {
           MessageBox.Show("No data.");
         }


        client.Close();
```

**Server:**
The server will listen for data. When it receives data it will check if it's apple and then reply "Yes".

```
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(1334);
        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

            string request = sr.ReadLine();

            if(request == "apple")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(request); // Print that to the console so we know it was received okay
                sw.WriteLine("yes\n");
                client.Close();
            }
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I see two things: add a `sw.Flush()` on the Server side before `client.Close();`, and since you haven't posted the whole code it is unclear if the client waits for the response, afaik `ReadLine()` is a nonblocking call - it will continue if the server did not respond in time.

Comment: @Furmek "add a sw.Flush() on the Server side before the client.Close();" That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Furmek commented:

> I see two things: add a sw.Flush(); on the Server side before
>   client.Close();

**Working Server Code**

```
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(1334);
    listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

        string request = sr.ReadLine();

        if(request == "apple")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(request); // Print that to the console so we know it was received okay
            sw.WriteLine("yes\n");
            sw.Flush(); // sw.Flush(); Added here!!
            client.Close();
        }
```